# Custom Magento transactional email template file location

Tags: ee-1.13, transactional

I'm currently in the process of creating a number of custom transactional email templates and was wondering if someone could recommend the best place to store the HTML for them within my theme?

I will be using the admin to override the default templates, allowing other users to make changes when needed. I was wondering if I should be putting them someone within my themes template folder instead?

I'm currently using Git and it would be good to ensure that the templates are in version control if required.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest solution:** keep editing your email templates via Magento Admin.

**Alternative solution:** copy the files you want to edit from `/app/locale/[you_language]/template/email/` to `/app/design/frontend/[your_theme]/default/locale/[your_language]/template/email/` and edit them. But then you will need an extension to make Magento override the default template with your custom one. It is not supported out of the box.

More info here: https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-theming/1670-customizing-magento-email-templates